# How to use presigned URLs with different domain names

Tags: minio, pre-signed-url

Minio container startup command

```sh
sudo docker run -p 13456:9000 --name minio-manisha-manual  -e "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=manisha" -e "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=xxxx" -v /home/manisha/files/images:/data minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-05-26T00-22-46Z server /data
```

I am trying to get a presigned url and upload an image using presigned URL.

```py
# Getting presigned url
minio_client = Minio(localhost:13456, access_key=manisha, secret_key=xxxx, secure=False)
resp = minio_client.presigned_put_object("nudjur", "nginx.png", expires=timedelta(days=1)
```

Result I get is http://localhost:13456/nudjur/nginx.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=manisha%2F20210526%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210526T190513Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=c491440d5be935e80371d15be30a695328beab6d434ba26ce8782fe93858d7a5

As the DNS for my server is manisha.something.com, I would like to use manisha.something.com as host to upload pre-signed URL. So I tried modifying presigned URL host to my DNS manually like below

http://manisha.something.com:13456/nudjur/nginx.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=manisha%2F20210526%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210526T190513Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=c491440d5be935e80371d15be30a695328beab6d434ba26ce8782fe93858d7a5
When I tried to upload to this URL I am getting *SignatureDoesNotMatch error*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><Key>nginx.png</Key><BucketName>nudjur</BucketName><Resource>/nudjur/nginx.png</Resource><RequestId>1682B2C4E4049CC6</RequestId><HostId>c53990e5-e9ad-46aa-bd28-87482444d77b</HostId></Error>
```

Can someone help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: Also looking for the solution to this issue

Comment: You could use proxy while configuring minio client, please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75129663/11049184