# accessing the minio object presigned get URL both from inside and outside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, fastapi, minio

I used the following docker-compose.yml file to deploy a FastAPI, MongoDB, Minio docker containers.

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    user: 1000:1000
    volumes: 
      - /home/krishna/mongodb/db:/data/db

  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - /data:/data

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: imaging_container
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

From inside the FastAPI, I am able to connect to the minio instance using **minio:9000** endpoint. API returns the output of *get_presigned_url* for a requested minio object but the url is in the form of *http://**minio:9000**/imaging/images/30d12c89...* which I am not able to access from outside the docker container.

I found a quickfix/workaround to resolve this i.e. adding this line to */etc/hosts* file works

```
127.0.0.1       minio
```

But this looks to me a cheap solution where host has to modify his/her machine.

I feel like this can be resolved easily by adding **nginx proxy** to the docker container. But I am not sure how to go about doing that?

It would be helpful if you can suggest the nginx configuration setup to resolve this, or alternatively any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can try exposing port through docker port fowarding (network)
or
Please have a look at the guides:
https://docs.min.io/docs/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio

Answer (score 1):

You could use another address for signing (for example, `localhost:9000` to access it from your computer's network). And then, you could apply proxy to the Minio client, so that it would make the actual request to the container in the docker network.

I have managed it to work with the following code (example in dotnet):

```cs
MinioClient client = new MinioClient()
    .WithEndpoint("localhost:9000")
    .WithCredentials('----', '-----')
    .WithProxy(new WebProxy('minio', 9000)) // configuring proxy here
    .WithSSL(false)
    .Build();
```